# MAMP Pro can't see index /

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, osx-yosemite

I'm testing MAMP Pro demo and I created a few wordpress folders in the htdocs of the MAMP folder. Whenever I attempt to launch the WebStart, I get to a web page that tells me MAMP Pro was correctly installed, but whenever I attempt to access the localhost:8888 page, instead of seeing the index of wp instances, I only get this message:

The virtual host was set up successfully.

If you can see this page, your new virtual host was set up successfully. Now, web content can be added and this placeholder page1 should be replaced or deleted.

Server name: localhost
Document root: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

1 Files: index.php and MAMP-PRO-Logo.png

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: If you created the wordpress content in folders, then don't you need to access those folder (i.e. correct the URL you are using in the browser)?

Comment: From what I've seen in all YouTube tutorials, MAMP Pro allows a user to manage multiple Wordpress instances by placing all WP folders in htdocs and then, by simply loading lcalhost:8888, see an index of all wp instances and choose the one to work on. Somehow, I only keep seeing the placeholder files and not the wp folders.

Answer (score 3):

Helo, in my case, the problem was solved by removing index.php and reloading the project folder in htdocs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder that the files are in and see if there’s a file in there called ‘index.htm’ or ‘index.html’. Basically, anything like that isn’t ‘index.php’ (that’s the WordPress file). If you find that, then delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file index.php hopefully you'll fix that problem

Comment: Do note that this answer already exists and is upvoted.